# Referencing 'this' from a class that is not extending JavaPlugin

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to make a plugin that starts a Scheduler task with this method:

```
public void newCountdown() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (Player player : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()) {
                player.sendMessage("Hey");
            }
        }                   
}, 0, 20);
}
```

The problem is, when I try to call the method, it says it needs to be a static method. Then, when i change it to static the first parameter "this" says it cannot be used in a static context.

When the method is not static, the `scheduleSyncRepeatingTask` shows this error:

> The method scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Plugin, Runnable, long, long) in the type BukkitScheduler is not applicable for the arguments (activateDevMode, new Runnable(){}, int, int)

When I try any of the quick fixes it gives me, it will always result in another error.

Is there a way to reference `this` from the Main class without having to make my method static?

Comment: `this` and `static` will never work well together. The whole point of `static` is to indicate the lack of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because [`static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [`this`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) never go together. An easy way to think about it is that `static` removes the object-oriented part of Java. `this` is a keyword that points to the current instance of your class, and cannot be used with `static` because using a `static` variable is like completely removing instances all together.

You will have to change `this` to an instance of your `Main` class (the one that `extends JavaPlugin`). You can initialize a static variable `onEnable()` to store the instance

```
public static Main that; //"Main" will be replaced with the name of your Main class

@Override
public void onEnable(){
    //set that to an instance of your Main class (this)
    that = this;
}

@Override
public void onDisable(){
    //set that to null to prevent memory leaks
    that = null;
}
```

Now, you can make your `newCountdown()` method static by replacing `that` with `this`

```
public static void newCountdown() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(Main.that, new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(Player player : Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()){
                player.sendMessage("Hey");
            }
        }                   
    }, 0, 20);
}
```