# register listener throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to use the [Bukkit PingAPI](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/pingapi.3829/) to create a fake player counter on the client server list, but it keeps throwing `NullPointerExceptions`

Here's my code

```
package mpolder;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import skionz.pingapi.PingAPI;
import skionz.pingapi.PingEvent;
import skionz.pingapi.PingListener;


public class fakePlayer
        extends JavaPlugin
        implements PingListener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        PingAPI.registerListener(new PingListener() {
            public void onPing(PingEvent event) {
                event.getReply().setOnlinePlayers(5000);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onPing(PingEvent event) {
        event.getReply().setOnlinePlayers(5000);
    }
}
```

And here's the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at skionz.pingapi.PingAPI.registerListener(PingAPI.java:26) ~[?:?]
    at mpolder.fakePlayer.onEnable(fakePlayer.java:19) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:316) ~[spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:329) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:405) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:476) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:394) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:866) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:301) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:23) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:181) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:767) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:753) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.aB(DedicatedServer.java:326) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.DedicatedServer.v(DedicatedServer.java:290) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.u(MinecraftServer.java:584) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:490) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R4.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:628) [spigot_server.jar:git-Spigot-1544]
```

Comment: Where is line 19 in your code?

Comment: Line 19: PingAPI.registerListener(new PingListener() {
            public void onPing(PingEvent event) {
                event.getReply().setOnlinePlayers(5000);
            }
        });

Comment: Jup, its one registerListener line

Comment: I think i figured it out but im running into other problems now :l, i think its because i have multiple onEnable and JavaPlugin classes. Im trying to add the Jar where i get the event from but its giving an error on packaging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752071/intellij-external-libraries-package-x-does-not-exist

Comment: (I'm pretty sure) that wouldn't be causing a `NullPointerException`. It would be causing a [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html). Also, you can only have *one* class that `extends JavaPlugin`. If you want to get it's methods elsewhere, [check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31258653/2767207). And only have one `onEnable()`.