# IntelliJ External libraries package X does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I added some external libraries to my project and in the editor intelliJ is not giving me any errors, when I compile it though it gives me errors saying:

> [ERROR] /C:/Users/martijn2/IdeaProjects/fakePing/src/main/java/mpolder/fakePlayer.java:[3,26] package com.skionz.pingapi does not exist
>
> [ERROR] /C:/Users/martijn2/IdeaProjects/fakePing/src/main/java/mpolder/fakePlayer.java:[4,26] package com.skionz.pingapi does not exist
>
> [ERROR] /C:/Users/martijn2/IdeaProjects/fakePing/src/main/java/mpolder/fakePlayer.java:[5,26] package com.skionz.pingapi does not exist

How do I import API's into my intelliJ and make them package with all my other stuff?
I use IntelliJ + Maven

Comment: Sounds to me like the problem is that you have, in fact, already brought the packages into IntelliJ; what you need to do is add them to the Maven POM. But this post is awfully short on details so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: How do i add it to the pom? Thats probably it...

Comment: That would entail adding a `<dependency>` to the `<dependencies>` block. If you don't know how to do this, I would recommend you read through the [Maven Getting Started Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html) (skip down to "How do I use external dependencies"), as going into the details here is a bit above the scope of an SO comment or even answer.

Comment: Why (and How) to add the in the pom? I think that the question talks about an external library to be added directly through File -> Project Structure... option.
Exact same behavior here. @martijnp, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @ElPiter Yes, what I think was happening was that it was packaging without the dependencies included. I believe I had to configure something like this for it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven